# unable to connect to database mysql by java application

Tags: java, mysql

This is simple code to connect mysql database, the username and the password are right.
I can't connect to mysql database.
Any suggestion?

```
package provaconnessionemysql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class connessionemysql {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("inizio programma connessione mysql");

        try {Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registropeso/" + "user=andrea&password=password");
            System.out.println("connessione aperta");
            conn.close(); // termino la connessione
            System.out.println("connessione chiusa");
        }

        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("LocalizedMessage: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            System.out.println("Message: " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Hashcode: " + e.hashCode());
            System.out.println("Cause: " + e.getCause());

        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + e.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + e.getErrorCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any exceptions?

Comment: There are many reasons why you *might* not be able to connect. **What** exception do you get?

Comment: There's no `?` in this url to indicate you're providing parameters: `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registropeso/" + "user=andrea`. It should be `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registropeso/?" + "user=andrea`. I vote to close since this is a typographical error.

Comment: I added the "?" as suggested but it still does not work

Comment: this is the output of console:inizio programma connessione mysql;
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
LocalizedMessage: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
Message: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
Hashcode: 1950409828
Cause: null

Answer (score 0):

The getConnection() method already has the user and password parameters.

`getConnection(String url, String user, String password)`

Just specify it respectively.

`Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registropeso/","andrea","password");`

Comment: I changed the connection string as suggested but it still does not work

Comment: I have got no error compilation. this is the output of console:inizio programma connessione mysql; java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver; LocalizedMessage: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver; Message: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver; Hashcode: 1950409828 Cause: null

Comment: Did u add the jdbc jar file in your classpath?  If using eclipse ide, add the path in `Java Build Path --> Libraries --> Add external jars`. Download it from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: I never did, i think it was incluse.anyway i'm using datasource now and it works!thanks i'll try with drivemanager later